# How to use get all content from API using cURL

Tags: php, mysql, php-curl

I have an API that has 418 pages with data, i am trying to get all the content in the API and put them in my MySQL database.

Currently i can only put the first page content inside the database. How do i solve this?
Here is my Code.

data.php

```
<?php

include_once './config/Database.php';

$url = "http://exampledomain.com/api/properties";

$ch = curl_init($url);

$headers = array(
  'Content-type: application/json',
  'API_KEY: 2S7rhsaq9X1cnfkMCPHX64YsWYyfe1he',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

if($e = curl_error($ch)){
    echo $e;
}
else {
    $decoded = json_decode($resp,true);
    // print_r($decoded);
    $query = 
            "INSERT 
              
              INTO 
                  details 
                  (
                    county,
                    country,
                    town,
                    description,
                    displayable_address,
                    image,
                    thumbnail,
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    bedrooms,
                    bathrooms,
                    price,
                    -- property_type,
                    type
                  ) 
              VALUES 
                  (
                    :county,
                    :country,
                    :town,
                    :description,
                    :address,
                    :image_full,
                    :image_thumbnail,
                    :latitude,
                    :longitude,
                    :num_bedrooms,
                    :num_bathrooms,
                    :price,
                    -- :property_type.description,
                    :type
                  )
              ";
      //Prepare Statement     
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
     

      //Bind data
      $stmt->bindParam(':county', $county);
      $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
      $stmt->bindParam(':town', $town);
      $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
      $stmt->bindParam(':address', $displayable_address);
      $stmt->bindParam(':image_full', $image);
      $stmt->bindParam(':image_thumbnail', $thumbnail);
      $stmt->bindParam(':latitude', $latitude);
      $stmt->bindParam(':longitude', $longitude);
      $stmt->bindParam(':num_bedrooms', $bedrooms);
      $stmt->bindParam(':num_bathrooms', $bathrooms);
      $stmt->bindParam(':price', $price);
      // $stmt->bindParam(':property_type.description', $property_type);
      $stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);

    foreach($decoded["data"] as $decode){

      $county = $decode['county'];
      $country = $decode['country'];
      $town = $decode['town'];
      $description = $decode['description'];
      $displayable_address = $decode['address'];
      $image = $decode['image_full'];
      $thumbnail = $decode['image_thumbnail'];
      $latitude = $decode['latitude'];
      $longitude = $decode['longitude'];
      $bedrooms = $decode['num_bedrooms'];
      $bathrooms = $decode['num_bathrooms'];
      $price = $decode['price'];
      // $property_type = $decode['property_type']['description'];
      $type = $decode['type'];
      

      
    $stmt->execute();
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Database.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "api-call";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Database Connected successfully and Record Addedd"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above code is only inserting the contents on the first page to the database, i want to insert all the contents from page 1 to 418 to the database.

Comment: Does the API provide parameters for switching pages?

Comment: Oh yeah it does ```http://exampledomain.com/api/properties?page%5Bnumber%5D=418"``` but i do not understand what %5number%5D means

Comment: In this case, you need to inquire from the API vendor about the use of each param. You will also need a loop, to iterate all those pages and retrieve the data you want.

Comment: so, you should put all your curl codes inside a function with the `$page_no` parameter and after that try to get content from API by page and repeat that function inside a foreach

Comment: This is the parameter ```page[number]=3``` to go to page 3. How do i ensure all the page contents enter the database? I am new to this